# VBA Create an array with numbers 1 through some calculated value

Tags: arrays, string, excel, vba

**Question:**

How can I create the following array without knowing the ending number before hand:

```
myArray = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

For example, I can do something similar in Python:

```
myList = range(ending_number)
```

As well as in Matlab:

```
myVector = 0:ending_number
```

**More Detail:**

I have a path being specified in an Excel worksheet that references a location on a Linux server.  I want the user to only have to specify the path in terms that the Linux server understands, but also need to reference a location in terms that both the local Windows machine and the Linux server understands.  The Linux server path is specified as

```
/home/shelf6/some/path/to/a/location/on/the/server
```

and the corresponding path in Windows is specified as

```
\\SB1\home_shelf6\some\path\to\a\location\on\the\server
```

I am currently converting from one to the other with the following commands:

```
WinJobLoc = Split(LinJobLoc, "/", -1, vbTextCompare)
WinJobLoc = "\\sb1\" & WinJobLoc(1) & "_" & WinJobLoc(2) & "\" & _
             Join(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(WinJobLoc, 0, _
             Array(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)), "\", vbTextCompare)
```

However, since I will only be able to know the length of the path from `UBound(WinJobLoc)`, I don't know of an easy way to get the portion of the path following "`shelf6`."

Is there some way to do what I'm trying to do (i.e. without the hard-coded array), or is there an easier way to do the whole thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be reading the question wrong but should this be enough:

```
Sub stringModify()
Dim LinJobLoc As String
Dim WinJobLoc As String

LinJobLoc = "/home/shelf6/some/path/to/a/location/on/the/server"

LinJobLoc = Replace(Right(LinJobLoc , Len(LinJobLoc ) - 1), "/", "\")

WinJobLoc = "\\SB1\" + Replace(LinJobLoc, "\", "_", , 1)
End Sub
```

But this does not answer your question to answer that you have two options:

One is you use a ReDim on the Array

The second option is to not use an array but instead use a collection.

Comment: This is nice, but did you intend the first `LinJobLoc` to be `s1` instead?  If not, please specify what `s1` is so I can mark your solution as the answer.

Comment: Oh yeah that was testing then I added in your values. it is updated now, I used s1 as String 1 in testing.

Comment: It would be simpler if the `WinJobLoc` command were `WinJobLoc = "\\SB1\" + Replace(Replace(LinJobLoc, "/", "\"), "\", "_", 2, 1)`.  This would also allow `LinJobLoc` to be referenced later (assuming that the second `LinJobLoc` command were removed since it would be unnecessary with that change).

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
Sub ArrayCreator()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter a number", Type:=1)
    ReDim myarray(0 To N) As Long
    For i = 0 To N
        myarray(i) = i
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Indeed this accomplishes what I was trying to do, but I was hoping to be able to find the most concise means of accomplishing my ultimate purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Just re-read from the linux path, starting from an offset equal to the sum of the lengths of the elements you have already used, plus slashes, swapping path chars;

```
Dim ArrWinJobLoc() As String, WinJobLoc As String

ArrWinJobLoc = Split(LinJobLoc, "/")

WinJobLoc = "\\sb1\" & ArrWinJobLoc(1) & "_" & ArrWinJobLoc(2) & _
    Replace$(Mid$(LinJobLoc, 3 + Len(ArrWinJobLoc(1)) + Len(ArrWinJobLoc(2))), "/", "\")
```